# Android Signed Apps

Tags: java, android, communication, self-signed

I am trying to publish an app which can be used by other applications (meaning others apps can invoke my application to do some service for them). However I see that when I sign my app using my default.keystore and other application (who want to communicate with my app) which are signed by some other default.keystore cannot communicate or invoke my app.

If both my app and other app are signed with same keystore they are able to communicate.

Can you someone please guide me how can I sign an application and let other signed app invoke it?

Comment: What do you mean by communicate? And what do you mean by invoke your app?

Comment: That's right, I want other apps to Invoke my application.

Comment: Can you have your app set up as a ContentProvider?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using eclipse try this...

right click your project ,select **Android Tools** and select **Export Signed application package**

Then select **create new key store.**give all the details and do as described.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. If I create a new key store, can my application be capable of being invoked by other apps? (who I assume would do the same procedure for signing their apps?)